# Qual framework JavaScript me indicaria para criação de DOM Object dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Qual framework JS me indicaria para criar objetos em Html dinamicamente?

Por exemplo: preciso criar um botão com classe "btn-exemplo" e que faz referência ao link do site do Google(ao clicar, abre o site). Porém, vou fazer isto apenas quando uma dada variável booleana for true. O algoritmo para inserir o elemento na árvore do DOM seria:

```
if ( variavelBooleana ) {
  var botao = document.createElement('input')

  botao.value = 'Google'

  botao.class = 'btn-teste'

  botao.onclick = function () { window.location.href = 'google.com' }

  document.body.appendChild(botao)
}
```

Desconsidere erros porque o que eu realmente quero é fazer isto:

```
if ( variavelBooleana )
  frameworkEspecificoQueFazIsto.addElemento('input',{class: 'btn-teste', value: 'Google', onclick: function () { window.location.href = 'google.com' } })
```

Espero que tenha compreendido e possa me ajudar. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de se usar um `input` se o objetivo é criar um botão (e se é um link, deveria ser uma âncora, `<a>`, não um botão), mas de qualquer forma, por que não apenas implementa essa função que você deseja ao invés de utilizar um framework?

Comment: Estou buscando este framework para um projeto da empresa em que trabalho. Nós temos um módulo que deve armazenar uma string de JS para ser usada dinamicamente(não vou entrar em detalhe por ética profissional). Preciso do framework mais rápido possível, pois não é apenas um simples input ou button que iremos utilizar, mas talvez uma img ou form, etc... Compreende?

Comment: Aparentemente é mais fácil "desenvolver" do que "procurar algo pronto". 

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Será que o jquery não te atenderia?

```js
var button = $('<input type="button" class="sua_classe_css">').val('nome_do_botao').click(function () {
  window.location.href = 'SEU_LINK';
});

$('body').append(button);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Dá uma olhada e vê se atende você amigo!

E tem também a lib [zepto](https://zeptojs.com/) seria parecido ao jquery mas é mais leve e não tem tudo que o jquery possui, mas parece que te atende!
um exemplo do site deles:

```
// create element:
$("<p>Hello</p>") //=> the new P element

// create element with attributes:
$("<p />", { text:"Hello", id:"greeting", css:{color:'darkblue'} })
//=> <p id=greeting style="color:darkblue">Hello</p>
```